How can I create a single NuGet package that's targetting .NET 9 and .NET Framework 4.8.1 at the same time?
I'd like to create a NuGet package for a WPF library component that I'm writing.
As I'm using WPF classes, I cannot use .NET Standard. So, I need to target .NET 9 and .NET Framework 4.8.1 at the same time.
The component is supposed to fulfill the following requirements:

Compile and build in a single project (i.e., <TargetFrameworks>net481;net9.0-windows</TargetFrameworks>)(Nullable types enabled ??????)
Run the same set of tests for both target frameworks ??????
Pack them all in a single NuGet package ??????

Is this possible, without much ado?

Yes, this should work. dotnet pack will pack it and you could create a test project wihh the same TargetFrameworks to run tests under both too. This sort of multi-targeting is common; if you're running specific issues you should ask about them.

It seems like NuGet does have an issue with this setup: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/13936
